# Webdriverio browser.keys('Down arrow') is not working for a specific custom drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, drop-down-menu, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I have two different drop-down in one webpage the difference between both is that for the first drop-down the first option is selected by default and I can use browser.keys to select options as there is no select/option tags available. But in the second drop-down the first option is not selected by-default and browser.keys is also not working in this case.

1. [image: first drop-down]
2. [image: second drop-down]
3. [image: drop-down inspection]

I just want to select option of both the drop-downs, please let me know if there's a better approach for handling such drop-down menu options.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I figured it out i needed browser.performActions:

```
await browser.performActions([{
            type: 'key',
            id: 'keyboard',
            actions: [
                {type: 'keyDown', value: '\uE009'}]
        }]);
```

I was still having an issue even after arrow down button worked so i just added another action pause just like wait so my actions section looks like this:

```
actions: [
            {type: "pause", duration: 2000},
            {type: 'keyDown', value: "\uE009"},
            {type: "pause", duration: 2000}
            ]
```